# A verb to describe specific positioning of three layers

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am describing the positioning of three layers stacked on top of each other in a scientific paper. The first and third layer made from the same material, but the layer in between (i.e. the second layer) differs from the two other.

I would to put the description in the following context.

> The module consist of two layers of A that ....[*a verb*]...a layer of B

What verbs best suits the context here?

Comment: Sounds like a sandwich to me.

Comment: ".. consists of a layer of B between two layers of A"

Comment: consider *interstitial layer*

Comment: @Fattie - *between* isn't a verb. But *separating* is.

Comment: @Mazura - that's very interesting.  Isn't "layer of B" just the noun phrase and the rest is just a modifier?

Comment: Is the shape of these layers planar? An onion, for instance, is also formed from layers but they aren't planar. I can imagine complex mathematical structures also having this property.

Comment: @DaveInCaz The layers have planer shape and stacked on top of each other like glass sheets

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An appropriate word would be:

> **sandwich** [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sandwiched)
>
> > transitive verb
> >
> > 1 : to make into or as if into a sandwich
> >
> > especially : to insert or enclose between usually two things of another quality or character

As in *The module consists of two layers of A that sandwich a layer of B*.

---

However,  I think a more natural phrasing uses **sandwiched by**:

> The module consists of a layer of B **sandwiched by** two layers of A

The may not sound like the most scientific term, but it is frequently used in composite material papers. See [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877705816344563) that lists "sandwich structures" as one of its keywords. Other articles can be found by using similar search terms.

Comment: There is nothing unscientific about this usage. _Sandwich_ is a perfectly respectable verb.

Comment: "Sandwiched between" sounds much more natural to me than "sandwiched by", and is [a lot more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sandwiched+by%2C+sandwiched+between&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csandwiched%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csandwiched%20between%3B%2Cc0), too :)

Comment: And for what it's worth "Sandwich" does appear in the technical language of Calculus: The Sandwich Theorem (Also called the Squeeze Theorem). I'm sure I could find a paper on arXiv that uses the sandwich language. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem

Answer (score -1):

While the verb *sandwich* will be readily understood, yet another word which should work is ***flank***.

> The module consist of two layers of A that ***flank*** a layer of B

Lexico/ODO:

> **[flank](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/flank)**
> *VERB*   [WITH OBJECT]
> **1** **Be on each** or on one **side of**.
>
> ‘Two black leather sofas flanked a low table in front of the receptionist, and Wendy chose one.’

Comment: This works, but it doesn't include two specific meanings of sandwiched: close physical contact, and flat layers.

Comment: _Flank_ suggests side-by-side contact, instead of a vertical stacking. And why use it anyway, when _sandwich_ is perfect for the job?

Answer (score -1):

What you're asking for is a verb, however what you're describing here is the position of things relative to other things. So (in my opinion) what fits better here  is a preposition.

"The module consists of three layers: one layer of B, and two *adjacent* layers of A"

You could also use adjoining:

"The module consists of three layers: one layer of B, with two *adjoining* layers of A"

Comment: These both sound somewhat ambiguous to me as to the ordering of the layers. It's not clear if the *adjacent*/*adjoining* describes the two layers of A in relation to each other, or each layer of A in relation to the layer of B.